# To select dropdown value in selenium using name

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below is my code.

This is my combobox/dropdown box

```
<TR id="oldcontent" bgcolor="#D0D0D0">
<TD ALIGN="left" id="oldcontent">
<select name="status" style="width=150" id="newcontentformat">
<option value="15">Approved1</option>
<option value="16">Approved2</option>
<option value="17">Approved3</option>
</TD>
</TR>
```

how do i select the value Approved2?can anyone help me with the xpath?

I tried the below..but its not working

```
selenium.select("//select[@name='status']",Approved2);
selenium.select("status",Approved2);
```

Also i have multiple  and  and i need to select the combobox present in very first .

Thanks in Advance for help

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the method has to be a string. Try:

```
selenium.select("//select[@name='status']", "Approved2");
```